# VBA Error While Getting Index From Range Array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm working with multiple range arrays. Each array has one column range. I definded my arrays as a Variant Array. And I arranged one spinbutton to textbox to get value of exact input from array range.

Array example:

```
...    
fiber_oList = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sarfArray").Range("B2:B18").Value2
    mySpinButton.Max = UBound(fiber_oList, 1) - LBound(fiber_oList, 1) + 1
    mySpinButton.Min = LBound(fiber_oList, 1)
    Kal.Value = fiber_oList(mySpinButton.Value, 1)
...
```

and I have a function to get Index number of specific value from array.

```
Public Function whichIndex(araArray As Variant, vBul As Variant) As Integer
'
'
Dim i As Integer
If IsArray(araArray) Then
For i = 1 To UBound(araArray, 1)

 If araArray(i, 1) = vBul Then
    whichIndex = i
    Exit Function
  End If
Next i
whichIndex = Null
Else
MsgBox "Bu bir array değil."
End If

End Function
```

and then I used result of my function as below:

```
temp = whichIndex(fiber_oList, tekKal)
    mySpinButton.Value = temp
```

Code is working correctly for first array. But for second array it gives an error:

function gives result of `IsArray` function `FALSE`.

and VBA gives

> RUN TIME ERROR '380': Could not set the Value property. Invalid property value.

What can I do for this issue?

Comment: You are returning `Null` for non-arrays. Either return something else that `mySpinButton.Value` can accept, or do not set it to `temp` when `temp` is `Null`?

Comment: But all arrays have same length, and all indexes of arrays are filled with a specific value. Why it is returning NULL?

Comment: You said it yourself that `IsArray` is returning `false`. So that would not be an array.

Comment: Either I made my arrays copy of first array as trial. The code is working first array, but for the remaining function returns false for IsArray. I cannot understand what is the cause. All things are similar for each array, and code seems ok.

Comment: Put `Option Explicit` on top of your code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried but It didn't work.

Comment: Does your second array have one cell?

Comment: Each array contains 17 cells. For example : "A1:A17", "B1:B17" ... etc.

Comment: There's no real problem with the code you posted, so the issue is likely with what you *didn't* post, which is how you declared and populated your second array.  Exactly how did you copy your first array?

Comment: Your `whichIndex` function shouldn't make side effects (as you do with `MsgBox`). It should return some success or failure value. Only at this point you should raise message box. When you get `temp` variable, it can be `Null`, but you **do not** test for it and immediately assign it to `Value` property. That's why you receive this error.